# My Rails button is not updating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a button where users can input stuff in a field and then press the button to update the database (`put` request) which can be seen here in `show.html.erb`:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
        <br>
        <%= @user.email %>
        <% if @errors  %>
          <p>THE FORM COULD NOT BE SAVED </p>
          <ul id='errors'>
          <% @errors.each do |error| %>
            <li><%= error %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
        <br>
        <% if is_admin? %>
          <% if !@user.admin %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

                  <%= f.label :wistia_project_id %>
                  <%= f.text_field :wistia_project_id, class: 'form-control' %>

                  <%= f.submit "Save", :action => "set_wistia_project_ID", :method => :patch, :form_class => "form-control" %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>        
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

The function is in `user_controller.rb`:

```
  # Sets wistia_project_ID.
  def set_wistia_project_ID
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.set_project_id
    unless @user.valid?
      @errors = @user.errors.full_messages
      render :show
    end
  end
```

That function calls another function, just to separate things more clearly. This other function lives in `user.rb`:

```
  # Sets the wistia_project_ID.
  def set_project_id!(val)
    self.wistia_project_ID = val # self is necessary here
    save # or self.save, but the self is unnecessary here
  end
```

My `routes.rb`:

```
.
.
.
  resources :users do
    member do
      patch 'set_wistia_project_ID'
    end
  end
```

My problem is that right now, when you press the button, it says: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)` 
and

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `set_project_id' for #<User:0x000055b1a0914ab8>
2019-06-26T14:46:34.940086+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean?  wistia_project_id):
```

Comment: Your method is `set_project_id!(val)` and you are calling `set_project_id` with no `!` at the end and no val argument.

Comment: You're right, I just fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zavitoski got it right. I suggest, however, that you're doing a number of things more fundamentally wrong. Given that you're early in your rails journey, I hope you don't mind if I point a few things out.

First, and to be nit-picky, yes, you created a button. But, it is not a button "where users can input stuff in a field and then press the button to update the database". You created a button on a *form*. And you created a *field* on that form. The user can input stuff into the field. And when clicked, the button submits the form which includes the information in the field.

Now, on that form, you did:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :wistia_project_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :wistia_project_id, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save", :action => "set_wistia_project_ID", :method => :patch, :form_class => "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

There are a few things wrong with:

```
:action => "set_wistia_project_ID"
```

First, `set_wisteria_project_ID` is not a very ruby-ish action name. `set_wistia_project_id` would be more like it. Also, you're using old-form key-value formatting. And, you can use a symbol instead of a string for your action name so your code is prettier. Something, perhaps, like:

```
<%= f.submit "Save", action: :set_wistia_project_id, method: :patch, form_class: "form-control" %>
```

But, that's a mistake, too. Because you don't need a `set_wistia_project_id` action. (It's an `action` or a `method`, not a `function`.) You already have the `update` action. And `form_for` is smart enough to submit to this action if `@user` is an instance of `User`. So, really, you should do:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :wistia_project_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :wistia_project_id, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save", form_class: "form-control" %>

<% end %>
```

I'm not sure what `form_class` is, but I'll trust that it's correct.

Now, in your `UsersController`, just do:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController 

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if user.update(user_params)
      # do something successful
    else
      # do something unsuccessful
    end
  end

private

  def user_params
    # NOTE: You'll probably want to permit other stuff here, too.
    params.require(:user).permit(:wistia_project_id)
  end

end
```

Get rid of this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Sets the wistia_project_ID.
  def set_project_id!(val)
    self.wistia_project_ID = val # self is necessary here
    save # or self.save, but the self is unnecessary here
  end

end
```

Because you're just duplicating the `update` method. And, you probably want that attribute to be `wistia_project_id`, not `wistia_project_ID`. (Again, you never see `_ID` as the suffix in rails core and you might as well be conventional.) And, if you make sure you have your association set up correctly, ActiveRecord should make sure that `wistia_project_id` is actually a valid value.

And write your `routes.rb` like this:

```
resources :users
```

Because you don't need all that `set_wistia_project_id` business.

Comment: Okay, thank you! This really helps actually. I see that I made several mistakes, part of the learning process :D I'm going to try to implement these suggestions actually, since I havent gotten the DB udpate to work yet!

Comment: They worked smooth like butter thanks so much *6 Hours of Trial and Error Later* :D

Comment: Glad to help. So, em, *this* is the correct answer then? (hint, hint)

Comment: *shoots finger guns*

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are not calling the function by the name you defined, neither passing the parameter (project_id) needed.

```
def set_wistia_project_ID
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.set_project_id!(params[:wistia_project_id])
    unless @user.valid?
      @errors = @user.errors.full_messages
      render :show
    end
  end
```

This should use the function you created and pass the parameter from the form.